# node-postgres `date` type query not correct

Tags: node.js, postgresql, date, node-postgres

I am running a PostgreSQL 10 on a Vagrant VM Installed Version: 2.1.1 with the following OS:

- Distributor ID: Debian
- Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.4 (stretch)
- Release:        9.4
- Codename:       stretch

My locale setting on the server:

- LANG=en_US.UTF-8
- LANGUAGE=
- LC_CTYPE=de_AT.UTF-8
- LC_... ="en_US.UTF-8"
- LC_ALL=

`timedatectl status` gives me the following:

- Local time: Mon 2018-07-23 20:58:07 CEST
- Universal time: Mon 2018-07-23 18:58:07 UTC
- RTC time: Mon 2018-07-23 18:58:06
- Time zone: Europe/Vienna (CEST, +0200)
- Network time on: yes
- NTP synchronized: yes
- RTC in local TZ: no

My settings of my PSQL DB:

- `Select NOW();` gives me the right point of time.
- `show timezone;` is set to 'Europe/Vienna', which is the right timezone.

**The problem:**

I have a guest_group table with the following row:

`arrival_date DATE NOT NULL,`

and the following value:

`2018-07-23`

But when I query my DB everything works as expected, except that I get the following result:

`arrivalDate: 2018-07-22T22:00:00.000Z,`

Somehow I get the previous day, the 22nd and not the 23rd.

A DB query in the shell gives me the right date - `SELECT * FROM guest_group;`

---

**Update:** I am requesting the DB with NodeJS and [node-postgres](https://node-postgres.com). Everything works perfectly with the queries, except the date. After further research, I come to the conclusion that it has something to do with node-postgres and this [problem](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/510). Here is a similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49852123/date-conversion-in-nodejs-and-postgres). I will work on my final solution the next week and will share it here.

Comment: Are you sure your `arrival_date` is of Postgres type `DATE`? It looks like it is `TIMESTAMP` instead. What is the timezone the VM is set to?

Comment: Yes, this is my sql script in order to create the table:  `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS guest_group (
  booking_number VARCHAR(100) PRIMARY KEY,
  arrival_date DATE NOT NULL,
  departure_date DATE NULL,
  custom_fields JSONB NOT NULL,
  customer_id INTEGER REFERENCES customer (id) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE (booking_number, customer_id)
)
WITH (OIDS=FALSE);` When I use `timedatectl status | grep "Time zone"`  in the terminal on my VM I get `Time zone: Europe/Vienna (CEST, +0200)`